# Actionscript error cannot import library

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml, mxmlc

In the Below action script file i get an error saying cannot import mx.controls.Label,how is this to be resolved

```
  package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import mx.controls.Label;

    public class cld extends Sprite
    {
        public function cld()
        {
            var myLabel:Label = new Label();
            myLabel.text = "hello";
            addChild(myLabel);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you compiling your app?  Command line?  With Flex/Flash builder?  With some other tool?  Where/When do you get the error?   In the Flash Builder Console?  AT Compile Time?

Comment: I am compiling it through command line

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is Flex project and that in project properties->Flex Build Path->Library Path you import the framework.

Comment: He never said he was using Flash Builder.  If it was a Flex project, he shouldn't have to add the Flex framework info himself.

Comment: I realize that, but if it was AS project, or if he messed with the settings (or just some plain ol' bug) that thing could've been unset.